# How to redirect multiple scripts as one into bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

If I have a script file `script0.sh`, I can have bash run it as stdin like so:

```
bash -s < script0.sh
```

How can combine multiple script files (`script0.sh`, `script1.sh`, ...) into one "stream" (for lack of a better word) as if I did it with `cat script0.sh script1.sh ...` and redirect the result to bash as with the single file above with a single command?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: @jww, I'd would agree that U&L could accept this question as well, because bash is mainly used on Linux systems, but as I search for bash related answers on a daily basis, it doesn't seem like the answers are exclusively there. Sometimes U&L, sometimes Server Fault and a lot of it here, on SO. Most importantly, this question is about trying to achieve something using bash syntax. Bash *is* a programming language and I wasn't asking about specific Linux or otherwise server side use case so I'd say this one is pretty much on the money for SO. You could say the same about python cmd as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use process substitution:

```
bash -s < <(cat script0.sh script1.sh)
```

Comment: codeforester, a quick follow-up: the above works great on Ubuntu but throws `syntax error: unexpected redirection` on Alpine. Would you have any idea why?

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash` on Alpine?  Probably you shell doesn't support process substitution.

Comment: works with both `bash` and `sh` on Ubuntu and neither on Alpine

Comment: Apparently this has something to do with [posix compliance](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/shell-process-redirection). In Alpine `bash` setting `set +o posix` will make process substitution work but, unfortunately, not in Alpine `sh` as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

You may do exactly what you want using `cat` and a pipe `|`:

```
cat script0.sh script1.sh script2.sh ... | bash
```

The pipe takes the output of one command and makes it the input of another.

As a way to test:

```
$ echo "echo yes" | bash
yes
```

This works because `bash` will execute whatever it comes from its standard input. You may add the `-s` option which tells `bash` to do that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Javier. I'm aware of `pipe` and my question was specifically about `redirect`.